# Java ArrayList how to check if one of the rectangles contains the mouse?

Tags: java

I have an application where you place tiles. You can place tiles over tiles and I don't want that. I know that I need something like if the tile rectangle contains the mouse then don't place a tile over it. But this doesn't work. Look at this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < b.toArray().length; i++) {
    b.get(i).tick();

    if (b.get(i).r.contains(Comp.mx, Comp.my)) {
        canPlaceATile = false;
        //  System.out.println("yes");
    }
    else {
        canPlaceATile = true;
        //System.out.println("no");
    }

    if (b.get(i).remove) {
        b.remove(i);
        i--;
    }
}
```

This is how I check if the mouse is inside the area of one of the tiles.

Block class:

```
public abstract class block {

    public int x,id;
    public int y;
    protected Image img;
    public boolean remove;
    public int rotate;
    public Rectangle r;

    protected int bx, by;

    public block() {
    }

    public abstract void tick();

    public abstract void render(Graphics g);

    public void createCollisionRect() {
        r.setBounds(x - (int) play.camx, y - (int) play.camy, 20, 20);
    }
}
```

an example of a tile:

```
public class wall extends block {

    public wall(int x, int y, int rot) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.rotate = rot;
        r = new Rectangle(x - (int) play.camx, y - (int) play.camy, 20, 20);
        id = 0;
    }

    public void tick() {
        createCollisionRect();

        if (Comp.mr && r.contains(new Point((Comp.mx), (Comp.my)))) {
            remove = true;
        }
    }

    public void render(Graphics g) {
        ImageIcon i62 = new ImageIcon("res/tiles/wall.png");
        img = i62.getImage();
        g.drawImage(img, x - (int) play.camx, y - (int) play.camy, null);

        g.setColor(Color.red);
        // g.drawRect(x -(int)play.camx, y - play.camy, 20,20);
    }
}
```

I want to check if any of the rectangles contains the mouse and set canPlaceATile to false if the mouse is inside one of the rectangles. The code above doesn't work because when I print the console and I have my mouse over one of the tiles it says:

```
yes
no
yes
no
yes
no
yes
no
yes
no
yes
no
yes
no
yes
no
yes
no
yes
no
yes
no
yes
```

and this is when my mouse is on the rectangle without moving it at all. How can I fix this so that I cannot place tiles on top of tiles. Her is where I place tiles:

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
        Comp.ml = true;
        if (manager.isplay && play.dragging == false) {
            if (play.canPlaceATile) {
                if (play.selectedID == 0) {
                    play.b.add(new wall((Comp.mx / 20) * 20, (Comp.my / 20) * 20, play.selectedRot));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is missing some central pieces that are used in the sample. What is play? What is comp? Is the collision code executed in the game loop? Anyway: I think from what I can extract from your code, that you are creating a collision rectangle reduced to wall coordinates, but you check against mouse coordinates, that are screen coordinates. But this is just a wild gues, because your variable names are so non-speaking, that it is really hard to understand the sample (at least for me).